# Return the Address of a set object via iterator

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, set

I have a set of elements of type Team. I want to write a function to return the address of a given element. The get_team function takes an id and compares it through a Team class function 'is_team' which returns the boolean value 'true' if that Team object has the same id.

```
1   string TeamA = "ABC";
2   Team A = get_team(TeamA);
3   
4   const Team & get_team(string id) {
5       for (set<Team>::iterator iter = teams_.begin(); iter != teams.end(); ++iter){
6           Team team = *iter;
7           if (team.is_team(id)){
8               return *iter;
9           }
10      }
11  }
```

When this runs, the address of *iter (line 6, line 8) is correct and matches the address of the Team object stored in the set 'teams_'.
However when the function returns the address is different (line 2).

The address of the element and that *iter correctly displays is: 0x0048e930
The address of Team A is: 0x0039f47c

How do i get the correct address? (How do i make the address of Team A 0x0048e930?)

Comment: Sounds like u wanna use a map instead of a set..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be specific about addresses, you would want to use pointers all the way. Else the mistake u are making is `Team A =` vs `Team& A =` due to which the returned reference gets copied, and this is why the address changes. It would be a stack address on top of it.